# Azure App service API app host vs API app

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

I have a question, I created recently an API app using visual studio 2017, I noticed that the name of the app says it's "API app host" which is different from the earlier one created a year ago "API app".
the problem that I am facing is that while I am trying to publish using visual studio 2017, the application that has "API host app" isn't listed at all as a candidate in the list.
as a workaround I am downloading the publish profile from azure portal and using that to publish using visual studio, as the last one can't find the targeted API app in the list.
is this a known issue ?
[this picture shows that we have two types of API apps, API App and API app host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWW7Y.png)

Comment: It could be something with the name of it. Not sure. I've never see "API app host" in there before.

Comment: I've seen this before. Most probably your API App was created with an older SDK while the bits were Preview. Just delete the API App from the Portal and recreate it. You should then be able to see it in the Publish wizard in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the [Azure SDK 2.5.1 Release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) installed on your VS, you should be able to see something similar to the image below, this is how you can publish to App Api.
[image]